# Imitating an ObservableCollection class with an IList

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm using [SQLiteNet-Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) to implement a `OneToMany` relation between a `Playlist` and an `IList` of `Track`.

At the moment the only supported collection types by the library are `List` and array (I changed the library to allow `IList` as a `List`).

Now I want to be able to be notified whenever my **collection** of Tracks is modified (add, remove, clear), but `ObservableCollection` is not allowed by the library (and I don't want to change the library too much as well).
This means I'm trying to recreate an `ObservableCollection` as follows:

```
class ObservableIList<T> : IList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    private List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
        OnPropertyChanged("magical property name");
    }

    ....
}
```

So that my `Playlist` would look as follows:

```
class Playlist
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public Boolean isCurrent { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public ObservableIList<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

This seems like it should work, except that I don't know what `propertyName` I should use when adding a new `Track` to my `ObservableList`?

Or am I going the completely wrong way at this?

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` already implements `IList<T>` :)

Comment: can't you just create an observabecollection and populate it with the list from your library instead of reinventing the wheel? e.g. the code that creates a playlist will grab a list from your library and convert to observablecollection for your playlist

Comment: Can you open a ticket in the bitbucket project? I think it's doable and maybe it can be included it in the next release

Comment: @redent84 I've sorta hacked it together myself for testing, but I will add a ticket when I get home tonight :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite-Net Extensions already supports `ObservableList` as *ToMany property. It shouldn't be needed any workaround anymore.